# Prove gcd equality

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

How to prove in Euclidean ring $Z$ with $a\in Z$
  $$gcd(a^2+3, 3a+5)=gcd(a^2+3, 3a^2+5a, 3a+5)$$ 
?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: More generally, $\gcd(u,v) = gcd(u,kv,v)$

Answer (score 0):

We have the following three results:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be any integers not both zero. If $b \neq 0$ and $b$ divides $a$, then $$ \gcd (a, b) = b. $$
>
> Let $a$ and $b$ be any integers such that $b \neq 0$ and $a = bq + r$ for some integers $q$ and $r$. Then
>   $$ \gcd(a, b) = \gcd( b, r). $$
>
> Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be any integers at most one of which can be zero. Then we have
>   $$
> \gcd(a, b, c) = \gcd \big( a, \gcd(b, c) \big).
> $$

In our proof we will be using the above two results. So here is the proof:

> We note that
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \gcd\left( a^2 + 3, 3a^2 + 5a, 3a + 5 \right) &= \gcd \left( a^2 + 3, a(3a+5), 3a+5 \right) \\
> &= \gcd \left( a^2 + 3, \gcd \big( a(3a+5), 3a+5 \big) \right) \\
> &=  \gcd \left( a^2 + 3, 3a+5 \right),
> \end{align}
> $$
>   as required.

Hope this helps.

Please feel free to ask for explanation / justification of whatever point you are unsure of.